# Translation of 織草為茵 in context

Tags: translation, meaning-in-context, literary-chinese

I am translating Dai Hongci‘s diary. He is describing an Austrian school for young nobles (貴冑學堂）. The above has a slightly unexpected word order. I am wondering, whether I understand it correctly (as grass interwoven into a thick mattress) , or whether 織草 is a plant name (cotton or something).

Below are the context (sentence by sentence), my German translation, as well as my rush attempt at an English one. A photography of a print, which I appended below, can be found [here](https://ctext.org/library.pl?if=gb&file=104394&page=313):

---

格致器械室、藏书室，藏籍颇富。/
Das Zimmer mit den naturwissenschaftlichen Apparati sowie die
Bibliothek bergen zahlreiche Bücher. /
The room with the natural sciences equipment and the library room contain plenty of books.

观马房，旁为练马场。/
Besichtigung der Stallungen.
Daneben befindet sich das Übungsgelände der Rösser. /
Inspection of the stables. Next to them there is the training ground for the horses.

> 堂后因山为园，林木优胜，织草为茵。/
> Hinter der Schule, an die Berge grenzend,
> ist ein Garten zu finden.
> Des Waldes Bäume sind zahlreich und florieren,
> die Gräser wachsen dicht wie eine Matte./
> Behind the school, adjacent to the hills, there is a garden (or park). Its trees are numerous and flourishing. Its grass is thickly interwoven as a mattress.

TLDR: I understood 因 without 草字頭 as 連接, adjacent because of the Song poem: 水边小丘因古城, 上有巨竹数百个

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

织草为茵 (Weaving grass into a carpet/ grass is woven into a carpet) is the literal meaning

It figuratively describes the scene as 'densely grown grass look like a woven carpet' (you can imagine it was very short grass)